# Removing right swipe gesture from list view using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently on my app i am populating a list view with various results which contain a slider, if the user right swipes they have the option to delete it, when they left swipe it nothing happens. Currently the slider can be hard to use because of the swipe motion in the list view, i want to keep the delete function in but is there any way i can remove the right swipe action? My app is cross platform but i would prefer to remove this from iOS.

This is how i am adding swipe functions:

```
         <ViewCell.ContextActions>

        <MenuItem  Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
           Text="Remove" IsDestructive="True" />

       <!-- <MenuItem Clicked="OnEdit"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
           Text="EDIT"  IsDestructive="false" />  -->
     </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

Comment: Add code otherwise it's all speculation you see! and yeah also add the custom renderer code

Comment: @G.hakim thats how i am currently adding the swipe actions, code updated.

Comment: so you want to stop the long press and left swipe functionality here?

Comment: @G.hakim No currently when you press the it directs you to another page which is needed, the right swipe allows the delete option to appear, their is no function when you left swipe but it stills moves the row across, i wanted to no if there was any way to eliminate the left swipe altogether . Im using a slider in each row and it can be quite hard to move up and down at times due to these swipes, but i think i need to keep the delete function in. Is this possible ?

Comment: If you have the right swipe you cannot stop the left one in my knowledge you cannot even do it in native iOS

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have discovered so far is to use the `IsEnabled` property. The swipe action/button will still appear, but it will be greyed out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem#enable-or-disable-a-menuitem-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use SwipeView control inside Listview or CollectionView

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview